# hyperlink to next section in navigation symbols jumps to last frame when in last section

Tags: beamer, hyperref, navigation, hyperlink

On this beamer document, when in the last section:

[image]

If you click on "Next Section", the desirable result would be to stop here, since this is the last section. However, if you click on "Next Section", you will go to the last frame inside this last section:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the desirable result (i.e. When we are in the last section, if we click on "Next Section", don't jump).

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}
\newcounter{prevsec}

\title{Some Title}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \setcounter{prevsec}{\thesection}
        \ifnum\theprevsec>1
            \addtocounter{prevsec}{-1}
        \fi
    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
    \quad\hyperlink{Detailed_Analysis}{\beamergotobutton{Detailed Analysis}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
    \quad\hyperlink{sec:\theprevsec}{\beamerskipbutton{previous section}}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}%
}


\begin{document}

   \section{sec1}
    \begin{frame}%{ss}
    1st section/ page 1 out of 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    1st section/ page 2 out of 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=Detailed_Analysis]
        Detailed Analysis
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}
    \begin{frame}
    2nd section
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \begin{frame}
    3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    Even More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will disable the hyperlink in the last section. It requires at least 2 compilations.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}
\newcounter{prevsec}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\title{Some Title}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \setcounter{prevsec}{\thesection}
    \ifnum\value{prevsec}>1
       \addtocounter{prevsec}{-1}
    \fi
    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
    \quad\hyperlink{Detailed_Analysis}{\beamergotobutton{Detailed Analysis}}%
    \ifnum\value{section}<\totvalue{section}%
        \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
    \else%
        \quad \beamerskipbutton{Next section}%
    \fi%
    \quad\hyperlink{sec:\theprevsec}{\beamerskipbutton{previous section}}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}%
}


\begin{document}

   \section{sec1}
    \begin{frame}%{ss}
    1st section/ page 1 out of 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    1st section/ page 2 out of 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=Detailed_Analysis]
        Detailed Analysis
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}
    \begin{frame}
    2nd section
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \begin{frame}
    3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    Even More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't rely on `\theprevsec` or `\thesection` to contain only numbers. Use `\ifnum1<\value{prevsec}...\fi` rather (I know, the O.P. has the code already)

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your helpful comment!

Comment: @samcarter: By the way: Congratulations to your lead in the TUG membership competition....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :) This is all your doing -- without your nomination and your kind words ... I thank you very much for this!